# setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage: + Storyboards

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, user-interface, uitabbar

I have my interface completely laid out with Storyboards (including the UITabBarController and all corresponding views).

Now comes the time to customize the Tab Bar. Since I have icons that are already set to the correct colour, I can't use `[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:]` (it just keeps looking wrong).

Turns out I'm supposed to use `setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage:` on the specific UITabBarItem's.

**Is it possible to use this method from the AppDelegate (where the rest of my global customization occurs)? How does the AppDelegate know which UITabBar to target?**

**If instead, I'm supposed to customize each UITabBarItem from each UIViewController, how do I reference the UITabBar (or "root view controller"?) and then specific item from the UIViewController?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Since you quoted my answer on your questions as the accepted response, please accept it as the correct answer using the checkmark button. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` of your `UIViewController` instances, you can do

```
[self.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage: withFinishedUnselectedImage:]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self) {
        [self.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"t1s"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"t1"]];
        [self.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Title"];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Also, delete image in tabbar item from storyboard view

Comment: I would recommend setting the finished images in `viewDidLoad:` instead, because `initWithCoder:` will not execute if the ViewController is loaded programmatically. Although this particular question references the Interface Builder explicitly, this might not be the case for other users reading this.